# Scrollbar customization

Tags: html, css

I've the below HTML Code.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <div class="chat-box-new-div">
    <div class="chat-box-new-head">Frequently Asked Questions ..
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body chat-box-new">
      <ul class="questionsUl">
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here Basically, I've a parent and 2 child divs. and inside the second child div, there is some content and this is not limited, more the content, we should get a scroll bar to scroll (This is working fine currently).

I'm using `overflow` to get the scrollbar, but the issue is like this,

1. If I take the scroll bar on the parent div, the scroll is working till the end.
2. When I take the same in the child div, it is not scrolling the entire content.

But I want the scroll in the second div(the child div) and display the entire data.

here is a working fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/a1zhffka/

please let me know how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/a1zhffka/2/

You need to add the overflow to `chat-box-new`. From your question it sounds like you already tried this, but your main issue was the `height`. The height of the div should be the height of the container, minus the height of the header. By having too tall of a height, the content will be cut-off.

For this specific example, `461px` seems like the sweet spot.

```
.chat-box-new {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 461px;
}
```

And remove the scroll from the parent:

```
.chat-box-new-div {
  height: 502px;
  border: 2px solid #157DEC;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #157DEC;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

For future consideration, you can avoid hard-coding all the heights if you give your header a fixed-height of say `50px`, and then use `height: calc(100% - 50px);`

Comment: Was typing the same answer, well let's go to the next question now :(